# Как вывести только последние показатели списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Доброй ночи, подскажите пожалуйста, как вывести только последние значения? Предчувствую, что ответ на поверхности, но я не могу его найти.. 
Дело в том, что это только сотая часть всего массива и нужно отсечь все лишнее.

```
a = ['aa', '1', '2', '1.5', '3', '2.1', '0.52', 'ab', '3', '4']  
def summ(list):  
    list = float(list)  
    item_list.append(list)  
    length = len(item_list)  
    s = sum(item_list)  
    k = s/length  
    mi = min(item_list)  
    ma = max(item_list)  
    return mi, ma, k  
for elements in a:  
    if elements.startswith('a'):  
        print('name', elements)  
        item_list = []  
    else:  
        print(summ(elements))
```

Выводится следующее:

```
name aa  
(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)  
(1.0, 2.0, 1.5)  
(1.0, 2.0, 1.5)  
(1.0, 3.0, 1.875)  
(1.0, 3.0, 1.92)  
(0.52, 3.0, 1.6866666666666665)  
name ab  
(3.0, 3.0, 3.0)  
(3.0, 4.0, 3.5)
```

необходимо, чтобы выводились только последняя запись, т.е.

```
name aa  
(0.52, 3.0, 1.6866666666666665)  
name ab  
(3.0, 4.0, 3.5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто запомните последние показатели и печатайте их, когда ясно, что последующих показателей не будет:

```
last = None
for elements in a:  
    if elements.startswith('a'):  
        if last is not None:
            print(*last)
            last = None
        print('name', elements)  
        item_list = []  
    else:
        last = summ(elements)
if last is not None:
    print(*last)
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь! Не подумал о таком варианте - думал именно в коде ошибка в выводе.

Answer (score 0):

для уcкорения выполнения можно воспользоватся [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html)

```
import numpy as np

a = ['aa', '1', '2', '1.5', '3', '2.1', '0.52', 'ab', '3', '4']

def summ(item_list):
    item_list = np.array(item_list).astype(np.float)
    mi = np.min(item_list)
    ma = np.max(item_list)
    k = np.divide(np.sum(item_list), item_list.size)
    return mi, ma, k

dt = {}
for elements in a:
    if elements.startswith('a'):
        ae = elements
        dt[ae] = []
    else: dt[ae].append(elements)
# {'aa': ['1', '2', '1.5', '3', '2.1', '0.52'], 'ab': ['3', '4']}

for k in dt: print(k, summ(dt[k]))
# aa (0.52, 3.0, 1.6866666666666665)
# ab (3.0, 4.0, 3.5)
```